# C++ Unresolved External Symbol using Template Linked Lists and Pass by Pointer

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, lnk2019, unresolved-external

**Please read the comments below**

Here is the specific error:

- Error 2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl totalPolynomial(class LinkedList *,class LinkedList *,class LinkedList *)" (?totalPolynomial@@YAXPAV?$LinkedList@VTerm@@@@00@Z) referenced in function _main
- Warning   1   warning C4805: '==' : unsafe mix of type 'unsigned int' and type 'bool' in operation    38

**I think the problem resides in sumPolynomial in functions.cpp/.h** Specifically with it's declaration/implementation.

header.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

#include "linkedList.h"
#include "term.h"

void loadPolynomial(string expression, LinkedList<Term> *theList);
void totalPolynomial(LinkedList<Term> *x, LinkedList<Term> *y, LinkedList<Term> *sum);
```

functions.cpp

```
#include "header.h"



void loadPolynomial(string expression, LinkedList<Term> *theList)
{
    Term tempPolynomial;

    string varDelimiter = "x";
    string posDelimiter = "+";
    string negDelimiter = "-";
    string token = "";

    double coefficient;
    double exponent;

    /*bool isNeg;*/
    bool removedCoefficient = false;

    while(expression.length() > 0)
    {
        /*isNeg = false;*/
        coefficient = 1.0;
        exponent = 1.0;
        removedCoefficient = false;

        if(expression.substr(0, 1) == "+")
        {
            expression.erase(0, 1);
        }

        /*else if(expression.substr(0, 1) == "-")
        {
            isNeg = true;
            expression.erase(0, 1);
        }*/

        if( expression.length() > 1 && expression.find(varDelimiter) == true)
        {
            //Get the coefficient
            token = expression.substr(0, expression.find(varDelimiter));
            //Remove the coefficient and variable from the string leaving only the exponent
            expression.erase(0, expression.find(varDelimiter) + varDelimiter.length());
            //Convert and put token's coeficient into a double
            coefficient = atof(token.c_str());

            /*if(isNeg == true)
            {
                coefficient = coefficient * -1;
            }*/

            //Put the coefficient value into the tempPolynomial
            tempPolynomial.setCoefficient(coefficient);
            removedCoefficient = true;
        }

        if(expression.find(posDelimiter) > 0 && expression.length() > 0 && removedCoefficient == true)
        {
            //Get the exponent
            token = expression.substr(0, expression.find(posDelimiter));
            //Remove the exponent but leave the + 
            expression.erase(0, expression.find(posDelimiter) + posDelimiter.length());
            //Convert and put token's coeficient into a double
            exponent = atof(token.c_str());

            //Put the exponent value into the tempPolynomial
            tempPolynomial.setExponent(exponent);
        }

        if(removedCoefficient == false)
        {
            //Get the trailing number
            token = expression.substr(0);
            coefficient = atof(token.c_str());
            //Set it as the coefficient
            tempPolynomial.setCoefficient(coefficient);
            //Set the exponent as 0 so we know it doesn't include a variable
            tempPolynomial.setExponent(0.0);
            //Remove it from the string
            expression.erase(0, token.length());
        }

        //Intert the first term into the linked list
        theList->insert(tempPolynomial);
    }
}



void sumPolynomial(LinkedList<Term> *x, LinkedList<Term> *y, LinkedList<Term> *sum)
{
    LinkedList<Term> *tempNodeX;
    LinkedList<Term> *tempNodeY;
    Term tempTermX;
    Term tempTermY;
    Term newTerm;

    tempNodeX = x->getNext();
    tempNodeY = y->getNext();


    while(tempNodeX != NULL)
    {
        tempTermX = tempNodeX->getData();

        while(tempNodeY !=NULL)
        {
            tempTermY = tempNodeY->getData();

            if(tempTermX.getExponent() == tempTermY.getExponent())
            {
                newTerm.setCoefficient(tempTermX.getCoefficient() + tempTermY.getCoefficient());
                newTerm.setExponent(tempTermY.getExponent());

                sum->insert(newTerm);
            }

            tempNodeX = tempNodeY->getNext();
        }

        tempNodeX = tempNodeX->getNext();
    }
}
```

term.h

```
#ifndef TERM_H
#define TERM_H

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Term
{
private:
    double mCoefficient;
    double mExponent; 

public:
    Term();
    //Term(double coefficient);
    //Term(double exponent);
    Term(double coefficient, double exponent);
    ~Term();

    double getCoefficient();
    double getExponent();
    void setCoefficient(double coefficient);
    void setExponent(double exponent);

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, Term object);

    bool operator==(Term right);
    //friend bool operator==(Term left, Term right);
    bool operator!=(Term right);
    //friend bool operator!=(Term left, Term right);
    bool operator>(Term right);
    //friend bool operator>(Term left, Term right);
    bool operator<(Term right);
    //friend bool operator<(Term left, Term right);
};

#endif
```

term.cpp

```
#include "term.h"

Term::Term()
{
    mCoefficient = 1;
    mExponent = 1;
}


//
//Term::Term(double coefficient)
//{
//  mCoefficient = coefficient;
//  mExponent = 1.0;
//}
//
//
//Term::Term(double exponent)
//{
//  mCoefficient = 1.0;
//  mExponent = exponent;
//}



Term::Term(double coefficient, double exponent)
{
    mCoefficient = coefficient;
    mExponent = exponent;
}



Term::~Term(){}



double Term::getCoefficient()
{
    return mCoefficient;
}



double Term::getExponent()
{
    return mExponent;
}



void Term::setCoefficient(double coefficient)
{
    mCoefficient = coefficient;
}



void Term::setExponent(double exponent)
{
    mExponent = exponent;
}



ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, Term object)
{
    if(object.mExponent > 0)
    {
        output << object.mCoefficient << "x" << object.mExponent;
    }

    else
    {
        output << object.mCoefficient;
    }
    return output;
}


bool Term::operator==(Term right)
{
    if(mExponent == right.mExponent && mCoefficient == right.mCoefficient)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}



bool Term::operator!=(Term right)
{
    if(mExponent != right.mExponent)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else if(mCoefficient != right.mCoefficient)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


bool Term::operator>(Term right)
{
    if(mExponent > right.mExponent)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else if(mExponent == right.mExponent && mCoefficient > right.mCoefficient)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}



bool Term::operator<(Term right)
{
    if(mExponent < right.mExponent)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else if(mExponent == right.mExponent && mCoefficient < right.mCoefficient)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

linkedList.h

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H
#define LINKED_LIST_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    T mData;
    LinkedList<T> *mNext;

public:
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(T data);
    ~LinkedList();

    T getData();
    LinkedList<T> *getNext();

    void setData(T data);

    void display();
    void insert(T data);
    bool isExist(T data);
    void remove(T data);

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, LinkedList<T> object);

    bool operator==(T right);
    friend bool operator==(T left, LinkedList<T> right);

    bool operator!=(T right);
    friend bool operator!=(T left, LinkedList<T> right);

    bool operator>(T right);
    friend bool operator>(T left, LinkedList<T> right);

    bool operator<(T right);
    friend bool operator<(T left, LinkedList<T> right);
};



template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList()
{
    mNext = NULL;
    mData = T();
}



template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(T data)
{
    mNext = NULL;
    mData = data;
}



template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
{
    LinkedList<T> *tempNode;

    tempNode = mNext;

    while(tempNode != NULL)
    {
        mNext = tempNode->mNext;
        tempNode->mNext = NULL;

        delete tempNode;

        tempNode = mNext;
    }
}



template <class T>
T LinkedList<T>::getData()
{
    return mData;
}



template <class T>
LinkedList<T> *LinkedList<T>::getNext()
{
    return mNext;
}



template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::setData(T data)
{
    mData = data;
}



template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::display()
{
    LinkedList<T> *tempNode;

    tempNode = mNext;

    while(tempNode != NULL)
    {
        cout << tempNode->mData << endl;

        tempNode = tempNode->mNext;
    }
}



template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insert(T data)
{
    LinkedList<T> *previousNode;
    LinkedList<T> *tempNode;
    LinkedList<T> *newNode;

    newNode = new LinkedList(data);

    if(mNext == NULL)
    {
        mNext = newNode;
    }

    else
    {
        previousNode = mNext;
        tempNode = mNext;

        while(tempNode != NULL && tempNode->mData > data)
        {
            previousNode = tempNode;
            tempNode = tempNode->mNext;
        }

        if(tempNode == mNext)
        {
            newNode->mNext = mNext;
            mNext = newNode;
        }

        else
        {
            previousNode->mNext = newNode;
            newNode->mNext = tempNode;
        }
    }
}



template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::isExist(T data)
{
    LinkedList<T> *tempNode;
    bool exist = false;

    tempNode = mNext;

    while(tempNode != NULL)
    {
        if(tempNode->mData == data)
        {
            exist = true;

            break;
        }

        tempNode = tempNode->mNext;
    }

    return exist;
}



template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::remove(T data)
{
    LinkedList<T> *tempNode;
    LinkedList<T> *previousNode;

    if(isExist(data) == false)
    {
        return;
    }

    tempNode = mNext;
    previousNode = mNext;

    while(tempNode->mData != data)
    {
        previousNode = tempNode;
        tempNode = tempNode->mNext;
    }

    if(tempNode == mNext)
    {
        mNext = tempNode->mNext;
        tempNode->mNext = NULL;
    }

    else
    {
        if(tempNode->mNext == NULL)
        {
            previousNode->mNext = NULL;
        }

        else
        {
            previousNode->mNext = tempNode->mNext;
            tempNode->mNext = NULL;
        }
    }

    delete tempNode;
}



template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, LinkedList<T> object)
{
    output << object.mData;

    return output;
}



template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::operator==(T right)
{
    return mData == right;
}



template <class T>
bool operator==(T left, LinkedList<T> right)
{
    return left == right.mData;
}



template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::operator!=(T right)
{
    return mData != right;
}



template <class T>
bool operator!=(T left, LinkedList<T> right)
{
    return left != right.mData;
}



template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::operator>(T right)
{
    return mData > right;
}



template <class T>
bool operator>(T left, LinkedList<T> right)
{
    return left > right.mData;
}



template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::operator<(T right)
{
    return mData < right;
}



template <class T>
bool operator<(T left, LinkedList<T> right)
{
    return left < right.mData;
}

#endif
```

Comment: It is what the compiler is telling you: you have no definition of `totalPolynomial`. You only have the declaration.

Comment: Maybe a typo? `sumPolynomial` instead of `totalPolynomial` in `functions.cpp`?

Comment: Three questions: Why do you implement your own list? The C++ standard library have [many good containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). Why do you use pointers instead of references? And are you sure you link with the object file created from `functions.cpp`?

Comment: So the error was a typo. I'm still learning and I thought making my own list would be good practice with pointers. I thought you had to pass pointers like this? And can you help me figure out why totalPolynomial() doesn't total? It seems to skip the inner loop of `while(tempNodeY != NULL)1

Comment: @Angel I'm agree, implementing a linked list is a good way to learn about pointers. But consider this: In real C++ code (I mean C++ code, no C code) the usage of pointers in that way is very unusual. Pointers (via smart pointers) are used in general to share ownership of objects, not to deal with dynamic memory. To deal with dynamic memory the Standard Library provides a good set of secure and tested containers, such as linked lists (`std::list`), resizable arrays (`std::vector`), hash tables (`std::unordered_map`) etc

Answer (score 0):

Here is the revised loop that now works:

```
    while(tempNodeX != NULL)
    {
        tempTermX = tempNodeX->getData();

        while(tempNodeY != NULL)
        {
            tempTermY = tempNodeY->getData();

            if(tempTermX.getExponent() == tempTermY.getExponent())
            {
                newTerm.setCoefficient(tempTermX.getCoefficient() + tempTermY.getCoefficient());
                newTerm.setExponent(tempTermY.getExponent());

                //cout << tempTermX << " " << tempTermY << " " << newTerm << endl;
                sum->insert(newTerm);

                tempNodeY = y->getNext();
                tempNodeY->remove(tempTermY);
                break;
            }

            tempNodeY = tempNodeY->getNext();
        }

        tempNodeX = tempNodeX->getNext();
        tempNodeY = y->getNext();
    }
```